# Good books or resources for understanding OS, kernel and CPU architectures

Tags: operating-system, kernel, cpu-architecture

I need to learn the basic knowledge of OS, kernel and CPU architectures since some jobs do require those background.

Is there a good book or online resource that I can refer to.

Comment: Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective (2nd Edition)

Comment: Can the people down-vote my question show me how to ask the question so that it will not be down-voted. At this moment, I just don't have any concrete questions for each topic. If you down-vote, please list your simple reason.

Comment: I would say this question is more for the [programmers site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) then SO. Read the [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I really don't appreciate to separate different questions into different website. What the drawback should be if we include all kinds of questions inside SO. The only thing I learn from this classification is nothing but useless.

Comment: Think about it in [this way](http://xkcd.com/435/)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you had a specific OS in mind, but one of the best books on how the Windows operating system works "under the hood" is called [Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301). It describes in detail how everything from the kernel, to device drivers, and the file system all work.

If your looking for a good book on how CPUs and processors work, in general, I recommend [Computer Architecture: A Quantitative approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605967). Very good info there!

Also, some good resources on how CPUs work, with perspective to programmers, can be found from the [Intel technical library](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm). Everything is free to download there and it makes for some good reading!